# Running rspec parallel with capybara features

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a test suite which is using capybara & rspec using Ruby.
I am using the parallel_tests gem in order to run my tests in parallel using sauce.

Now this is great, but it splits up the workload into spec files rather than what I want which is using the capybara features or even better, the scenarios. My spec file looks like

publisher_spec.rb

Feature "Adding users to the publisher"
Scenario "using public groups"
Scenario "using private groups"

So I want to run each scenario as a parallel test, but it only looks at the spec files, forcing me to break up by spec file into multiple units. My test suite would run faster if I had 1 scenario / spec file, but that would ruin the readibility and ability to use "before" steps.

Anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many parallel processes there are and how many files (and how long they take).

`parallel_tests` implements an "evening out" strategy by logging how long each spec file takes to run, as explained in their [readme](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests#even-test-group-run-times).
If the files you have can not be evened out, splitting them apart is your only option.

There's also the new parallel gem [`paraspec`](https://github.com/paraspec/paraspec). It looks promising, but I have not yet tried it out with feature testing.